# Twitter API - getting the Tweet ID when posting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter, sttwitterapi

When i post a tweet from the API at times the Tweet ID changes post execution. I am using Ruby's [Twitter Gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter)

```
@client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = ENV['TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY']
  config.consumer_secret     = ENV['TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY_SECRET']
  config.access_token        = token
  config.access_token_secret = token_secret
end

post_result = @client.update_with_media(content, image_file)
post_permalink = post_result.id
post_result = post_result.to_json
```

I get the following response

```
{"created_at":"Wed Feb 08 11:13:49 +0000 2017","id":829287112583286784,"id_str":"829287112583286784","text":"You must agree that the Classic Coffee without Chicory tastes thousands times better #ClassicCoffeeBrews <link>"}
```

When I trying to access the tweet I get an error.

> https://twitter.com/PebbleInWaters/status/8292871125832867842

Manually browsing into the Users Timeline i find that the Tweet ID has been changed to `829287114386894848`

> https://twitter.com/PebbleInWaters/status/829287114386894848

Any idea how to rectify these?